# How to place section titles in the header, but not in the document?

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, context, context-mkiv

I need to place some `\part` titles within my document, but make them invisible in the text, and only appear within the table of contents and headers.

With this code, the `\part` titles are not found anywhere:

```
\setuphead[part][placehead=no, page=no, number=no]
\setupheadertexts[{\getmarking[part]}]
\starttext
    \part{Birds of South America}
\stoptext
```

By changing `\placehead` to equal "yes", the title is placed in the header and in the document:

```
\setuphead[part][placehead=yes, page=no, number=no]
\setupheadertexts[{\getmarking[part]}]
\starttext
    \part{Birds of South America}
\stoptext
```

How can I make `\part` invisible in the document, but visible in the table of contents and headers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `empty` setting for `placehead`:

```
\setuphead [part] [placehead=empty]
\setupheadertexts [part]
\starttext
  \completecontent
  \part{Birds of South America}
\stoptext
```

This does not place the part title on the page, but creates
markings for the headers and an entry in the table of
contents.

Furthermore, you don't need the `\getmarking` in `\setupheadertexts`. It is
sufficient to just write `part`. ConTeXt knows that it's a valid
mark and prints its value instead.